# Windows 10 - Screens leak through desktop and lock screen?

Tags: windows-10

If I go to my desktop or lock screen, some previous windows seem to still show faintly through. I'm guessing this is a "feature" for the lock screen being transparent, but it appears on my desktop as well.

[image: Screen leak through lock screen]

Comment: This feels a lot like a video driver issue and would recommend you start by reinstalling your video driver. Does this seem to happen in safe-mode or when doing a clean-boot as well?

Comment: @BenJacobson I'll have to test those later, am I the only one with this problem ^_^